# How to run a Julia file and see all subsequent functions that are called?

Tags: julia

I am trying to get an idea of all of the functions in my code that a specific script calls. Is there a way in Julia that I can run a file, and see all of the functions that are called specifically within my own code?

I know profiling may be an option, but I am unsure if that will actually give me functions names and if I could specify to only look through internal functions (I want to avoid base functions in the output).

Comment: I'm not proficient with Julia yet, but isn't this effectively [Profiling](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/profile/)?

Comment: Strange ideas using `--trace-compile` come to mind. It would only list functions that haven't yet been compiled though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is certainly not what you want but I'll archive the idea here anyways.

If you run `julia --trace-compile=calls.txt myscript.jl` with `myscript.jl` being

```
# myscript.jl
myfunc(a) = a^2

anotherfunc(b) = sin(b)+3

myfunc(4)

anotherfunc(1.23)
```

Julia will create a file `calls.txt` with the following content

```
precompile(Tuple{typeof(Main.myfunc), Int64})
precompile(Tuple{typeof(Main.anotherfunc), Float64})
precompile(Tuple{typeof(Base._atexit)})
precompile(Tuple{typeof(Base.uvfinalize), Base.TTY})
```

As you can see, it tells you that `Main.myfunc` and `Main.anotherfunc` have been called with `Int64` and `Float64` arguments respectively. Probably not quite what you want but perhaps an interesting idea to build upon.

Comment: In this case I'm glad that I shared it :)